# Separating an html page?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to add a php script at the bottom of
http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Instead the page organizes into three columns (currently there are two columns) - I tried using div, span etc but did not work.

Any help?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="/85F8F24785A4473C8E421CE3BA013AB7/BDDF6C15-A2CD-DC41-B3F5-12484CECDF34/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <title>Audio Recorder</title>

 <script src="js/audiodisplay.js"></script>
 <script src="js/recorderjs/recorder.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 <style>
 html { overflow: hidden; }
 body { 
  font: 14pt Arial, sans-serif; 
  background: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0;
 }
 canvas { 
  display: inline-block; 
  background: #202020; 
  width: 95%;
  height: 45%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px blue;
 }
 #controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
 }
 #record { height: 15vh; }
 #record.recording { 
  background: red;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0000 0%,lightgrey 75%,lightgrey 100%,#7db9e8 100%); 
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0000 0%,lightgrey 75%,lightgrey 100%,#7db9e8 100%); 
  background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0000 0%,lightgrey 75%,lightgrey 100%,#7db9e8 100%); 
 }
 #save, #save img { height: 10vh; }
 #save { opacity: 0.25;}
 #save[download] { opacity: 1;}
 #viz {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
 }
 @media (orientation: landscape) {
  body { flex-direction: row;}
  #controls { flex-direction: column; height: 100%; width: 10%;}
  #viz { height: 100%; width: 90%;}
 }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="viz">
  <canvas id="analyser" width="1024" height="500"></canvas>
  <canvas id="wavedisplay" width="1024" height="500"></canvas>
 </div>
 <div id="controls">
  <img id="record" src="img/mic128.png" onclick="toggleRecording(this);">
  <a id="save" href="#"><img src="img/save.svg"></a>
 </div>
  
  <div
       <h2> Make sure it does not appear on a 3rd column </h2>
       <h2> Make sure it goes at the very bottom </h2>
  </div>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: what does adding a php script to the bottom of an html page have to do with columns?

Comment: SO does not serve that kind of help. You have shown zero effort, no code, no examples. Start with this http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: The code is in the link - http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html. One could just add a print statement at the bottom of the html code and see it themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the flexbox statements on the body. Introduce an additional container instead:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="/85F8F24785A4473C8E421CE3BA013AB7/BDDF6C15-A2CD-DC41-B3F5-12484CECDF34/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <title>Audio Recorder</title>

 <script src="js/audiodisplay.js"></script>
 <script src="js/recorderjs/recorder.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 <style>
 html { overflow: hidden; }
 body { 
  font: 14pt Arial, sans-serif; 
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0;
 }
    #main { 
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 80vh;
    }
 canvas { 
  display: inline-block; 
  background: #202020; 
  width: 95%;
  height: 45%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px blue;
 }
 #controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
 }
 #record { height: 15vh; }
 #record.recording { 
  background: red;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0000 0%,lightgrey 75%,lightgrey 100%,#7db9e8 100%); 
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0000 0%,lightgrey 75%,lightgrey 100%,#7db9e8 100%); 
  background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0000 0%,lightgrey 75%,lightgrey 100%,#7db9e8 100%); 
 }
 #save, #save img { height: 10vh; }
 #save { opacity: 0.25;}
 #save[download] { opacity: 1;}
 #viz {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
 }
    #bottom {
        height: 20vh;
    }
 @media (orientation: landscape) {
  #main { flex-direction: row;}
  #controls { flex-direction: column; height: 100%; width: 10%;}
  #viz { height: 100%; width: 90%;}
 }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
     <div id="viz">
      <canvas id="analyser" width="1024" height="500"></canvas>
      <canvas id="wavedisplay" width="1024" height="500"></canvas>
     </div>
     <div id="controls">
      <img id="record" src="img/mic128.png" onclick="toggleRecording(this);">
      <a id="save" href="#"><img src="img/save.svg"></a>
     </div>
    </div>
  
  <div id="bottom">
       <h2> Make sure it does not appear on a 3rd column </h2>
       <h2> Make sure it goes at the very bottom </h2>
  </div>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Steffi - can I add php script in <div id="bottom">? I tried putting  <?php
  $sessionId = $session->getSessionId();
  echo 'Session id = ' .$sessionId;
 ?> but the display is weird

Comment: You should be able to write any code (or simple text outputs) inside that bottom div.

Comment: - simplest is html page did not have a scroll bar on the right - running from a LAMP. The code is  <?php $sessionId = $session->getSessionId(); echo 'Session id = ' .$sessionId; ?> - did not look right

Comment: It shows the lines of php script on the webpage instead of executing I guess? eg. "getSessionId(); echo 'Session id = ' .$sessionId; ?> "

Comment: Is "getSessionId()" accessible from your html file? I'm not sure what you're trying to do. To get the current session you could use `$sessionId = session_id(); echo 'Session id = ' .$sessionId;` For further PHP question you should ask a new question with a php tag to get help from some experts.

Comment: Does the server needs to be told to look for php script in html?

Comment: Yeah, usually you have to uncomment the `LoadModule php5_module libexec/httpd/libphp5.so` and `AddModule mod_php5.c` lines in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Where can I find some detailed instructions on how to do it? Secondly why there is no scroll bar on the firefox?

Comment: For the installation instructions just use Google because it depends on which system you're using. For the scrollbar: add a `{overflow: auto}` or `{overflow-y: auto}` for the elements you want to see a scroll bar. Because you're using `vh` units for the elements' height you won't get a scroller for the page.

Comment: BTW, Turning the *.html extenstion into *.php does the trick! Thanks Steffi for your big help.